# Create .class file from a jar file -java

Tags: java, compilation, .class-file

I am using Java8. I have one .jar file containing .class files.

I downloaded the source code of the same .jar file. And I edited one of the file in it. It is .java file.

Now I want to compile all these .java files in the source code and create a new .jar file with .class files

Any clues?

Comment: have you used IDE, if its eclipse you can be able to create jar from IDE it self, no hard stuff from command you need to do @Soniya

Comment: I am using eclipse

Comment: Right click on project -> Export -> Java -> Jar file

Comment: Mine is a gradle project

The dependency is 
compile group: 'org.drools', name: 'drools-compiler', version: '7.0.0.Final'

I just want edit 1 file in  one of the jars

Comment: I think already done with modification, and you just want to make a build of that. Now i getting confuse what exactly you looking for, please elaborate a bit @Soniya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Compile the classes ([`javac` command](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html))

If you don't have any jar dependencies required at compile time, you should not need to set the classpath. 
Otherwise you should specify the `cp` argument with.
Example (Unix way) :

```
javac -cp "myLib.jar:myOtherLib.jar" *.java
```

2) Then create a jar from these compiled class ([`jar` command](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html))

Example :

```
jar cf myjar myFolderWithCompiledClass
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many options
1. if you want to do it from command prompt then you would need to set the classpath and then either create a list of java files with package name and use it for compiling, something like this

```
# Linux
$ find -name "*.java" > source.txt
$ javac  -classpath "${CLASSPATH}" @source.txt

:: Windows
> dir /s /B *.java > source.txt
> javac  -classpath %{CLASSPATH}% @source.txt
```

or use build tool like Ant.
Once you have the .class files, you can use "jar" command to create a jar of the .class files
2. Use IDE - you can use any of these IDEs - eclipe, intellij, netbeans. 
You need to setup a project with the java files and compile project and export as jar using class files.
I think it would work out better for you to use an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

extract your jar to a folder and run this:
javac [folder]/*.java

read that for more info:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html